How to persist simulated location after disconnecting iPhone from Xcode?
I want to simulate a location (longitude+latitude) on my iPhone. I created a small app in Xcode with a .gpx file containing the location, allowed location simulation and set default location for the app, then connected iPhone to Mac, ran the app on iPhone, and saw the location was being simulated on iPhone (such as with Google Maps). However, shortly after I disconnect iPhone from Mac, iPhone goes back to using its real location. Is there a way to persist the simulated location, such as until iPhone restart?

This used to work but I don't believe it has worked since iOS 16 or possibly even earlier.

@Paulw11 is there a any way to do it via other Xcode/Swift functionality?

I don't think so.  I think it is a loophole that Apple deliberately closed.
